# How to put input Text on EditText with CustomFilter and CustomAdapter

Tags: android, listview, filter, android-edittext, custom-adapter

I'm doing an app and I need to show a list of items. Each item has an image, name, price and Edittext to put de quantity of each item.
I've got a Custom Adapter and Custom Filter to filter the list of items that have on screen. But there is a problem with the EditText.
If I filter some items, if I change the Edit Text on position 3 change this EditText, but no the edittext that correspond to this item.

For example, I've got 5 items:

- Sugar
- Salt
- Pepper
- Sauce
- Lemon

If i write the letter "S" to filter, the screen only shows 3 items:

- Sugar
- Salt
- Sauce

But when I change the EditText of "Sauce" if I go back to the list of all items, change the line 3, ergo, the EditText of Pepper, but no the EditText of Sauce.

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: Add a quantity value to your model and then as the user types save the text to that variable within the model. This should maintain the position then

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't  understand what you want to tell me